# tsql iterate over xml soap response

Tags: xml, t-sql, parsing, soap

I am trying to iterate over the following soap response to get all the individual `eagResponse.text` values. The code below is not returning any values.

```
declare @ws_response_xml varchar(max)
set @ws_response_xml='<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
    <noppSendSmsMessageResponse xmlns="http://nopp.att.com/noppsendsmsmessageservice" xmlns:ns2="http://cio.att.com/commonheader/v3">
        <ResponseMessage>
            <ResultSet>
                <msgID>31891324</msgID>
                <sender>AA5555</sender>
                <recipient>BB5555</recipient>
                <phoneNbr>2222222222</phoneNbr>
                <message>test for backend ws call</message>
                <appName>notifications.gui</appName>
                <appLogID>TEST9999</appLogID>
                <response>inserted</response>
                <recptFlag>false</recptFlag>
                <errorFlag>false</errorFlag>
                <queueFlag>false</queueFlag>
                <eagResponse>Successful Send - SMSA9B1FD59AA82D7D9</eagResponse>
            </ResultSet>
            <ResultSet>
                <msgID>31891325</msgID>
                <sender>AA5555</sender>
                <recipient>ZZ5555</recipient>
                <phoneNbr>5555555555</phoneNbr>
                <message>test for backend ws call</message>
                <appName>notifications.gui</appName>
                <appLogID>TEST9999</appLogID>
                <response>inserted</response>
                <recptFlag>false</recptFlag>
                <errorFlag>false</errorFlag>
                <queueFlag>false</queueFlag>
                <eagResponse>Successful Send - SMSA9B63633F2476291</eagResponse>
            </ResultSet>
        </ResponseMessage>
        <inputEcho>BB5555;ZZ5555 - AA5555 - test for backend ws call - notifications.gui - TEST9999</inputEcho>
    </noppSendSmsMessageResponse>
</soap:Body>
```

'

```
declare @x as xml
set @x=@ws_response_xml;with xmlnamespaces('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' as [soap]
    ,'http://nopp.att.com/noppsendsmsmessageservice' as nopp
    ,'http://cio.att.com/commonheader/v3' as ns2)

select s.c.value('(text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') as eagResponse
from @x.nodes('/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/noppSendSmsMessageResponse/ResponseMessage') as m(c)
outer apply m.c.nodes('/ResultSet/eagResponse') as s(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

figured it out:

solution:the select should be written as below: (no need for the outer join because i'm not bringing in any top level data)

```
select m.c.value('nopp:eagResponse[1]','varchar(max)') as eagResponse
from @x.nodes('//soap:Envelope/soap:Body/nopp:noppSendSmsMessageResponse/nopp:ResponseMessage/nopp:ResultSet') as m(c)
```